# Setting select box option as 'selected' with css

Tags: css, wordpress

I am suing a wordpress contact form plugin that has a select box shortcode:

```
[select ID "option1""option2" "option3"]
```

Now in the browser, this will render as:

```
<select>
   <option>Option1</option>
   <option>Option2</option>
   <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

**What I need:**

I want to set the 2nd Option as the selected option, option2..

Now I know you do this by:

```
<select>
   <option>Option1</option>
   <option selected="selected">Option2</option>
   <option>Option3</option>
</select>
```

BUT I cannot define that in the shortcode, AND I DO NOT want to do it using jquery, to accommodate people not having javascript enabled...

**So how do I perhaps use CSS to set the second option as selected by default?**

Thank  you

Comment: you definitely cannot do this with CSS. CSS is for styling

Comment: Which plugin are you using?  why not modify the plugin code to suite your needs?

Comment: the plugin is "contact form 7". I customized the plugin to have 3 select boxes, and each select box generates a different mailto email address, but i want one of them to have a value, since all the values are set to blank by default ([select ID include_blank...])

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you could do here is probably switch the values around.

I'm not sure if that is a possibility for you but it's the easiest solution by far w/o having to go round messing with either CSS / JS

Comment: thanks, but I tried that, and it break something else in my solution. So I just have to go that route

Comment: Seems like the easiest solution but if there are other things depending on this list that require that first option to be there but just not selected, I simply wouldn't know but there probably is a way.